# How to trigger email notifications when using addListItem?

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Sites, one can subscribe to notifications when a list page changes, or rather when items or added and removed. However, it seems when the list items are created by a script, these email notifications do not occur. Is there another call or flag to set that would allow this to occur?

Comment: I think you should file a bug/enhancement request for this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similar feature request open in the Issue Tracker to add this behavior for Announcements in Sites. I've added your request to that one: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=710

Comment: Oh hey this is great. Thanks for doing that.